# Ubuntu Root Folder Hundreds of PHP Files

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu server that I just noticed has hundreds of files ending in .php.1 thru .php.1xxxx. I've been having timeout issues even though my max_execution_time is set to 0. Puzzled on this and wondering if this is causing my timeouts. Am I ok to wipe that folder of those files?

Comment: You are fine to wipe them if they aren't used anywhere in your code/app/site - unless they are :P On that note, spare files won't make servers timeout - and a script that has timed out probably wouldn't make a copy of a file - unless you have some other program installed that will make these.

Comment: I'd be pretty concerned if mystery files started appearing on my server but they sound more like a symptom of the problem you're having than the cause. If you have timeouts you can duplicate, xdebug would be the way to trace the problem, if it's random, something like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com) could help you keep an eye on things.

Comment: From the naming convention, my guess is that they are backups being created by some editor, although usually there would be a limit to that. However, without further details of your system, code, tools, etc, I doubt anyone will be able to do more than wildly guess at the cause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually using a wget in my crontab improperly. I switched from wget https://.... to /usr/bin/php5 and the php file path and everything is working without writing files. wget without any parameters such as -a downloads and writes a file. My mistake.